# Laravel 5 variable type hinting for requests

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to build a very general CRUD for Laravel, but I'm stuck at validation.

I have a RESTful resource controller, that will handle basic operations for any entity:

```
class CrudController extends Controller {
  public function store(StoreRequest $request) {...}
  public function update(UpdateRequest $request) {...}
  ...
}
```

Each actual entity has its own controller that extends it, say:

- ArticleController extends CrudController
- CategoryController extends CrudController
- TagController extends CrudController

So when you call the create() method in ArticleController() it basically calls CrudController::create().

So far so good. Now with the validation issue:

For the Article entity, I'd have the validation rules defined in:

- app/Http/Requests/StoreArticleRequest.php
- app/Http/Requests/UpdateArticleRequest.php

But classes for requests are already defined in *CrudController*, so Laravel will use those for type-hinting, so the executed validation will be the one from *StoreRequest* instead of the one I want, *StoreArticleRequest*.

How do I pass these classes to the *create()* and *update()* methods in *CrudController*?

CAN'T DO:

I don't want to redefine the *create()* method in *ArticleController*, because copy-pasting the *create()* function logic in each EntityController would lead to duplicated code. Also, they would have different parameters, which would trigger a "should be compatible with" PHP error.

ALREADY TRIED:

In CrudController:

```
use App\Http\Requests\StoreCRUDRequest as StoreRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateCRUDRequest as UpdateRequest;

class CrudController extends Controller {
  public function store(StoreRequest $request) {...}
  public function update(UpdateRequest $request) {...}
  ...
}
```

In ArticleController:

```
use App\Http\Requests\StoreArticleRequest as StoreRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateArticleRequest as UpdateRequest;

class ArticleController extends CrudController {
  ...
  // the create() and store() methods are no longer defined here
}
```

But it doesn't work, for ArticleController Laravel still runs the validation from App\Http\Requests\StoreCRUDRequest, defined in CrudController.

Any idea how I can make this happen?

Comment: Another ideal solution would be defining the create method in CrudController based on a variable, something like: public function store({$store_request_type_name} $request) {}

Comment: `StoreArticleRequest` could be extended from `StoreCRUDRequest`, by this way you are allowed to inject the request class in every children satisfying the type-hinting

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Stumbled on this trying to do something similar

Comment: Sadly, only something I'm not very proud of: in the child controller I've created some new methods, that call the parent methods. So in the example above, ArticleController has createArticle(StoreRequest $request) and updateArticle(UpdateRequest $request), each calling parent::create() and parent::update(). Not very proud of it... but it works. Please tell me if you find something else. It really bugs me.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than type hinting, you can use the `resolve()` helper to resolve the FormRequest class. See the [FormRequestServiceProvider](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Providers/FormRequestServiceProvider.php) on Line 33 and the [helper docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-resolve)

```
abstract class CrudController extends Controller {

    protected $modelClassName;   # Name of your model class
    protected $storeRequest;     # Name of your store FormRequest class
    protected $updateRequest;    # Name of your update FormRequest class

    public function store(): Model {
        $modelClassName = $this->modelClassName;
        $request = resolve($this->storeRequest);
        $instance = $modelClassName::create($request->validated());
        return $instance;
    }

    public function update($id): Model {
        $modelClassName = $this->modelClassName;
        $instance = $modelClassName::find($id);
        $request = resolve($this->updateRequest);
        $instance->fill($request->validated())->save();
        return $instance;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any reason against passing the Request objects into the constructor and letting Laravel inject them at runtime?

Example:

```
<?php
class ArticleController extends CrudController {

    use CreateOperation;

    public function __construct(StoreArticleRequest $storeRequest, UpdateArticleRequest $updateRequest)
    {
        $this->storeRequest  = $storeRequest;
        $this->updateRequest = $updateRequest;

        parent::__construct();
    }
}


trait CreateOperation
{
    /**
     * @var Request
     */
    private $storeRequest;

    public function setStoreRequest(Request $storeRequest): void
    {
        $this->storeRequest = $storeRequest;
    }

    public function storeCrud()   // parameter removed
    {
        $request = $this->storeRequest;

        ...
        ...
    }
}
```